# With these equations, if we know the initial number of people working in each sector in one year, we can estimate the number for all the following yer

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, nested, project

Example:

```
> M <- matrix(c(0.75, 0.2, 0.12, 
              0.1, 0.55, 0.22, 
              0.15, 0.25, 0.66), 
    ncol = 3, byrow = T)
> init <- c(30000, 40000, 30000) # initial number of workers

> fenwick_workforce(10, init, M)
```

**how can ı get below output?**

```
   Agro  Inds  Serv 
1  30000 40000 30000
2  34100 31600 34300
3  36011 28336 35653
4  36954 27030 36017
5  37444 26486 36072
6  37709 26248 36046
7  37857 26137 36009
8  37941 26083 35979
9  37990 26055 35958
10 38018 26040 35945
11 38035 26032 35936
```

Comment: Can you show the packages used for `fenwick_workforce`

Comment: check this [one](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/simhelpers/vignettes/simulation_workflow.html) may be useful

Answer (score 1):

There's no much information about what the `fenwick_workforce` function does, but based on your output, it looks like M is a Markov transition matrix.

You can get each row from the output by multiplying the previous row to the transposed transition matrix.

The following code outputs the expected:

```
M <- matrix(c(0.75, 0.2, 0.12, 
              0.1, 0.55, 0.22, 
              0.15, 0.25, 0.66), 
            ncol = 3, byrow = T)
init <- c(30000, 40000, 30000) 
Y <- matrix(NA, nrow=11, ncol=ncol(M))
Y[1,] <- init
for (i in 2:nrow(Y)) {
  Y[i,] <- Y[i-1,] %*% t(M)
}
Y
```

outputs

```
> Y
          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
 [1,] 30000.00 40000.00 30000.00
 [2,] 34100.00 31600.00 34300.00
 [3,] 36011.00 28336.00 35653.00
 [4,] 36953.81 27029.56 36016.63
 [5,] 37443.27 26485.30 36071.44
 [6,] 37708.08 26246.96 36044.96
 [7,] 37855.85 26136.53 36007.63
 [8,] 37940.11 26082.35 35977.54
 [9,] 37988.85 26054.36 35956.78
[10,] 38017.33 26039.28 35943.40
[11,] 38034.06 26030.88 35935.06
```